# ListRow.Delete method doesn't work on filtered table

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I am trying to figure out why the VBA `ListRow.Delete` method seems to work differently when my table is filtered and when it isn't.

I have a table with e-mail addresses, and have a column called `AutoCheck` with a formula that checks if the address fulfills my validity criteria. I also have a macro (tied to some buttons) that removes all the rows of the table that have the `AutoCheck` value at `False`:

```
Sub FixErrors()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim x As Long
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Kontakty")

    For x = tbl.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Columns(tbl.ListColumns("AutoCheck").Index) = False Then
            tbl.ListRows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x


End Sub
```

This works like a charm when I have the whole table displayed, but when I apply a filter and display only some entries (whether the offending rows are filtered out or not), the macro suddenly stops working! I have tried some debugging and remain completely baffled. I set a breakpoint at the line of `tbl.ListRows(x).Delete`, and it correctly identifies the offending row (a watch for `tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Columns(tbl.ListColumns("Email").Index)` displays the correct email I need to remove), but the `tbl.ListRows(x).Delete` just doesn't do anything, I step through it and nothing changes!

I'm sure I'm missing something here, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: It's a bug. I've reported it before but no response as yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info (and an extremely swift answer)! Well, that sucks, but at least now I don't need to worry about having missed something obvious:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour in Tables seems to be by design.  I'm not sure why it is so or what the consequences of allowing filtered table row deletion may be.  If you right-click a filtered table cell then go to Delete, your options are Table Columns or Entire Sheet Row.

Running your code throws a run-time 1004 at the `tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Delete` line:

[image: Can't move cells]

However, given the right-click Delete options described above, it should be possible to delete the `EntireRow`:

```
Sub FixErrors()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim x As Long

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Kontakty")

    For x = tbl.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Columns(tbl.ListColumns("AutoCheck").Index) = False Then
            tbl.ListRows(x).Range.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Tested in Excel 365 and it works!

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! It is strange though that you're getting that error with my code, it doesn't get thown for me (Office Professional Plus 2016, don't know if there's a difference in version, some settings or what). Anyway, your solution works for me! I don't have anything next to the table, so deleting a whole row is ok, even though it would have been nicer to not have the macro affecting any area outside the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
Sub FixErrors()

   Dim tbl As ListObject
   Dim x As Long
   Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Kontakty")

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   For x = tbl.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
       If tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Columns(tbl.ListColumns("AutoCheck").Index) = False Then
          tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Delete
       End If
   Next x

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your solution has a bit of an advantage over the other one in that it doesn't delete the whole row when the table is unfiltered. Mark's answer gave more clarity though, so I'm accepting his. In case anyone else is curious, with this solution, when you omit the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and the table is filtered, it asks you whether you want to delete the whole row. So in effect, it does the same as the other answer when the table is filtered, and deletes just the columns within the table otherwise.